# Automatically going to a div element created in React Virtual Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My webpage uses React components. At the render function of one of its components div elements that looks like:

```
<div id='myid'>
  {/* ... */}
</div>
```

are being used. After reloading a page we need to go to one of those divs. For example, after reloading that page we could automatically need to go to the `<div>` element with id equals to `myid`. Notice that that `<div>` is in React virtual DOM so functions like `document.getElementById` might not work (as it is happening with me). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The `<div>` and the `id` will end up in the document when the component is mounted, so you could scroll there in the `componentDidMount` hook.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById("myid").scrollIntoView();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ height: 1000 }}>Hello CodeSandbox</div>
        <div style={{ height: 1000 }} id="myid">
          Scroll here
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that we have several divs like the mentioned above with id='myid' within the same virtual dom page and we will like to, after reloading, sometimes go to one of them and sometimes to go to other.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga I understand. I updated the answer. It's just an example, but you could handle the logic for picking the `id` however you like.

Comment: You should use a react `ref` instead of searching the dom for the element. DOM querying is almost never neccesary when working with react.

Comment: I am starting to to consider a call back following this example. Thx

Comment: @trixn Yes, my original answer used `ref`, but that does not fit Jose's use case.

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga Okay i see but the problem is not with the `ref` but with the way to chose which element to scroll to. This problem still persists when just using an id to query the DOM. The server could e.g. set a global that the component can read to decide which element would need the ref.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get the element using findDOMNode

`const div = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.mydiv);`

Then in the render function

`<div ref="mydiv"></div>`

And at last

`window.scrollTo(0, div.offsetTop);`

Answer (score 0):

If the element is rendered by react you should use a `ref` to get the element to call `scrollIntoView()` on it:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    ref = elem => elem.scrollIntoView();

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.ref}>{/* ... */}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Using `getElementById()` or `React.findDOMNode` may also work but there you have the problem that you need to know if the component already mounted. If you do the scrolling inside the component (which is recommended) using a `ref` is the best solution.